# Formula for discriminant of a polynomial of degree 2 in 3 variables

Tags: discriminant

Which is the correct way/ method/Formula to find the discriminant of a quadratic equation  $f$ in 3 variables?

i.e., a quadratic form in 3 variables.
Also, how to conclude that, whether this $f$ is reducible or irreducible?

Some one knows this please help. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us write the general 2nd degree equation under the form:

$$\tag{1}ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+2dxz+2eyz+fz^2.$$

In order for (1) to be expressible under the form of a product of two first degree polynomials:

$$\tag{2}(px+qy+rz)(sx+ty+uz),$$

coefficients $a,b,c,d,e,f$ must satisfy the **pair of constraints** :

> $\tag{3}\begin{cases}b^2 + d^2 + e^2 - ac - af - cf & = & 0\\
> acf + 2bde - cd^2 - fb^2 - ae^2 & = & 0\end{cases} \ \ \ \text{with} \ \ \ a + c + f \neq 0.$

Here is a linear algebra explanation.

Let us write equation (1) under its classical matrix form :

$$\begin{pmatrix}x&y&z\end{pmatrix}\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}a&b&d\\b&c&e\\d&e&f\end{pmatrix}}_A\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$

Relationship (2) is known to be true (see Appendix) if and only if matrix $A$ has rank one, i.e., if and only if it has exactly two zero eigenvalues.

Expressing that $A$ has exactly 2 zero eigenvalues is the same as saying that its characteristic polynomial is equal to $-\lambda^3+k\lambda^2$ for some nonzero $k$.

Identifying $-\lambda^3+k\lambda^2$ to the characteristic polynomial of $A$:

$$\det(A-\lambda I_3)= - \lambda^3 + (a + c + f) \lambda^2 +(b^2 + d^2 + e^2 - ac - af -cf)\lambda + (acf + 2bde - cd^2 - fb^2 - ae^2),$$

we obtain conditions (3).

**Appendix :** Rank 1 property is due to the fact that (2) can expressed under the following form:

$$\begin{pmatrix}x&y&z\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}p&&\\&q&\\&&r\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&&\\&0&\\&&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}s&&\\&t&\\&&u\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}.$$

Remark : A quadratic form in three variables **set equal to 0** is the equation of a quadric surface passing through the origin. For example :

$$x^2+y^2-z^2=0 \ \ \text{is the equation of a circular cone with axis Oz.}$$

Expression (2), set equal to $0$, instead of a surface, corresponds to the degenerated case of 2 planes passing through the origin.

Remark: Let

$$\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}}_U, \ \ \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\-1&1&1\\0&-1&1\end{pmatrix}}_P, \ \ 
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}}_D \ \ $$

Rank-one matrix $U$ could have taken instead of rank-one matrix $D$ because

$$\tfrac13U=PDP^{-1}$$

(Columns of matrix $P$ are eigenvectors of $U$ resp. associated with eigenvalues $0,0,1$).

Comment: @ Jean, thank you very much for your wonderful answer.

Comment: May I ask why the Appendix holds? In my computation the middle matrix should be the $3\times3$ matrix with only $1$'s.

Comment: @The Great Seo See the remark I just added at the bottom of my answer.